# What's the httpd_module name so that Apache/Httpd works with PHP 5.5?

Tags: php, apache, centos, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I've been having some issues installing PHP 5.5 on a CentOS machine using **Chef**. I was finally able to install it, but when I access the `index.php` it just download a file with the content.

I'm guessing it's because Apache (technically Httpd, as I'm with CentOS) doesn't have `mod_php` installed/configured.

I installed PHP using [php cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/php) with the following packages:

```
# ... code to add webtatic repository to yum

node.set['php']['packages'] = ['php55w', 'php55w-devel', 'php55w-cli', 'php55w-snmp', 'php55w-soap', 'php55w-xml', 'php55w-xmlrpc', 'php55w-process', 'php55w-mysqlnd', 'php55w-pecl-memcache', 'php55w-opcache', 'php55w-pdo', 'php55w-imap', 'php55w-mbstring']
```

If I'm right, the code above didn't install `mod_php`. The following is my web chef recipe:

```
httpd_service 'apps' do
    mpm 'prefork'
    action [:create, :start]
    listen_ports ['80', '443']
end

# ... code for virtual hosts

# Install the mod_php Apache module.
# httpd_module 'php' do
#    instance 'apps'
# end
```

I had the `httpd_module 'php'` directive uncommented when using PHP 5.4. What's the correct name for the http_module to work with PHP 5.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've found one of the people who went the Debian route and set their packages up as `php55-` instead of `php-`. That makes things a pain if you want to go from 5.5 to any higher version, because you're having to uninstall those and install the new ones (i.e. `php70-`).

Instead I recommend switching your recipe to the [Remi repo](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en) and use the `php-` packages.

All that having been said, `php55w` is your base PHP package. I don't see a `php55w-common` package tho. Try adding that (or `php-common`) and that should get it into Apache.

Comment: So, `php55w-common` will setup apache mod?   Also, if I switch to remi repo, I can use `php-` packages meaning I dont have to overwrite my php packages for the `php55-` ones (and later the `php70- `ones)?

Comment: 1. Remi names them all `php-` and you just enable the proper repo for that version. Makes changing versions a snap. I just update my recipes to the right repo and then run a `yum update`
2. IIRC `php-common` contains the proper `.so` file for Apache. Its the only one I see in my list that isn't in yours(that's not a PHP library at any rate)

Comment: Ok then, I'll be using [yum-remi-chef](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/yum-remi-chef) cookbook to enable remi repo for php 5.5. After that I'll use the regular [httpd cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/httpd) and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life! Please add this as an answer so I can accept it. The problem was solved just by using the remi repo.

Comment: does remi repo include pecl? I may need to install `php-pecl-memcache`

Comment: Yep. He even built a working memcache library from a monkey patch for PHP7